# find all matches of list1 file in list2 file, create files and write relevant output to them. Python

Tags: python, list, find

I have two lists:

list1:

```
http://some.com
http://thing.com
http://whatever.org
```

list2:

```
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018010110231/http://some.com
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018012346789/http://some.com
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018002378231/http://thing.com
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018012346789/http://thing.com
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018012110231/http://whatever.org
http://www.totalywhatever.com/2018012346789/http://whatever.org
```

I want to create seperate file for each line from list1, with removing some signs. For example:

http://some.com , should create file called ---> some.com
http://thing.com --> thing.com
and so on...

To those files, links from "list2" containing relevant phrase,( so for  "some.com" it'd be first two lines from "list2"), should be copied to.

equivalent of linux:

```
grep some.com list2 > some.com  # Maan.. how complex operations on files can be ??
```

Of course it should go in the loop for all items...

I have came up with this one. It >>almost<< works, It creates correct files, but only put one link to each file instead of all matches. Any help'd be appreciated...

```
with open('list1', 'r+') as out, open('list2') as list:
o = out.readlines()
l = list.readlines()
out.seek(0)
for o1 in o:
         for l1 in l:
                 if o1.find(l1) > 0:
                         with open(l1.replace('http://', "").replace('\\n', '').rstrip(), 'w') as plik:
                                plik.write(o1 + '\n')
                                plik.seek(0)
                                plik.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read it I see, that I should've put "a" for append instead of "w" write in this line:

```
with open(l1.replace('http://', "").replace('\\n', '').rstrip(), 'w') as plik:
```

hope that helps someone!